# Node.js asynchronous use cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Recently, I have been developing web application and I realize that I am not making use of the asynchronous property at all. Hence I am ending up with a lot of nested callbacks.

For example, if the user want to get a file from the server through a particular API, I will have code similar to this,

```
db.query(<select list of permitted files_names>, function(err, filenames) {
   async.each(file_names, function(name, next) {
    //open each file to put into array
   });
})
```

This code needs to query database to get a list of file names before looping asynchronously and putting each file content into an array. Finally it will return the finished array to the client.

With the nested callback, and async library, this code is behaving like a synchronous code.

```
names = db.querySync(//select list of permitted files_names);
for(name in names) {
    //open each file to put into array
}
```

I am better off writing synchronous code like this since it is much neater. My use case might be a little strange but most of my api behaves in similar manner and that makes me think why do I even need asynchronous function?

Can someone please enlighten me if there are any differences between these two codes in term of performance? How do I make use of non-blocking property to enhance the performance in this use case?

Comment: Search for async/await in javascript

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ - why would async/await be relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're writing callback functions you're using by definition using async calls. The callback function fires *only* when the operation is complete or has errored out. You don't need a fancy library to use these, this is the backbone of how Node's [event-loop driven subsystem](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/) operates.

Node **strongly** advises against using "Sync" calls. The Node core only includes a handful as a convenience, they're there as last-resort tools. Many libraries don't even support them so you absolutely must get used to writing async code. In the browser environment, for example, you simply cannot use blocking calls without jamming up the JavaScript runtime and stalling the page.

I prefer using [Promises](https://promisesaplus.com) line [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) implements to keep code orderly. There are other ways, like the [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library, which can help manage otherwise complicated nesting patterns.

Some of the perks include things like `Promise.all` method runs a series of promises to completion and then triggers a next step, and `Promise.map` which iterates over a list, running async code for each element, then advancing when the list is complete.

If you're disciplined about organizing your code it's not too bad. Node does require a lot more attention being paid to the order of operations than in a traditional sync-by-default language like Ruby, Python or Java, but you can get used to it. Once you start working *with* async code rather than fighting it you can often do a ton of work quickly, efficiently, and with a minimum of fuss, in many cases more effectively than in other languages where you must juggle threads plus locking and/or deal with IPC.

Comment: Hi, regarding the above example, is the async vs sync version is the same? I am not losing concurrency in the synchronous version? I am abit confuse on whether concurrency refer to a single request or concurrency between many requests.

Comment: As soon as you make a Sync call everything grinds to a halt until that operation completes. For a database call that might mean your program does **nothing** for two or three seconds. This is completely unacceptable for production code.

Comment: The Sync calls I tend to make in programs are very specific and tactical, plus happen only during the initialization phase of the script so as to avoid causing problems during regular operation. For example, testing if a file exists before `require`-loading it, or iterating over a directory to load things in the correct order. Once the program's running it's async only.

Comment: Sorry if this question is irrelevant. But isn't operation such as variable declaration, pushing element into array etc.. synchronous behavior? Does that mean everytime I push element into an array, 100 clients have to wait for a single client to finish pushing?

Comment: @Zanko Yes, that's correct. But keep in mind that operations like adding an element to an array (inherently a synchronous operation) are orders of magnitude faster than querying from the DB (an asynchronous operation). Of course, in production environments, there are typically multiple web processes (e.g. 1-2 processes per CPU core).

Comment: On a micro-level, yes, these operations are blocking. Every operation you do takes non-zero time to complete. The art of writing good Node code is to keep each incursion as brief as possible: Don't do any heavy lifting. Break up your work into smaller chunks. Nibble away on big problems so other tasks have a chance to do their thing as well. If your operation takes more than 10ms to complete you should look at breaking it up. This is especially important in real-time applications. You don't want all your connections freezing up because of bad code.

Comment: @tadman, thank you so much, this clear my doubts. 
Final question. If I have two async function, one is to retrieve photo from database and another function is to retrieve 
list of friends, there is no point in nesting second function in the first function callback right? This makes me confuse between forcing synchronous 
workflow into two asynchronous functions. Nesting would make the second function wait on the first function, is this a bad practice?

Comment: If one async call is not dependent on the other then you can fire them at the same time and wait for both to finish. That's what that `async` library does, or in Promise terms: `Promise.all`. Async code like that is typically faster than sync code because both operations run at the same time. Instead of it taking N+M seconds, it takes the greater of N or M seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference in the two codes in terms of performance.

In synchronous code:

```
names = db.querySync(//select list of permitted files_names);
```

you are calling the database here to give list of names. Assume , this takes 10 sec. So for this time, nodeJS as it is single threaded gos into blocking state. After 10 sec, it executes the rest of the code . Assume this for loop takes 5 sec and some code takes 5 sec.

```
for(name in names) {
//open each file to put into array
}
//some code
```

Therefore it takes a total time of 20 sec.

whereas in Asynchronous code:

```
db.query(<select list of permitted files_names>, function(err, filenames) {
```

NodeJs will ask the database to give list of names to a callback. Assume that it takes 10 sec. And immediately it goes into the next step(some code), but not into the blocking state. Assume that some code takes 5 sec.

```
async.each(file_names, function(name, next) {
//open each file to put into array
});
})
//some code.
```

After 5 sec, it will check whether it has an i/o operations to be performed. Once the call back is returned. It will execute the function(name, next) {..} for the 5 sec.

So the total time here is 15sec.

In this manner the performance is improved.

If the asynchronous code should be clear and neat then make use of closures & promises.

For ex: Above asynchronous code can be written as

```
fun = function(err, filenames) {
 async.each(file_names, function(name, next) {
 //open each file to put into array
}
db.query(<select list of permitted files_names>, fun);
```

Answer (score 2):

The benefit is simple: By using asynchronous code, the current thread (remember, Node.js is single-threaded) is able to handle other requests while the current request is waiting on something (like a database query) to return.

If you use synchronous code instead, the current thread will block while it waits, and it won't be able to handle other requests in the meantime. In other words, you lose concurrency.

---

To keep your asynchronous code clean, look into promises (to avoid deeply nested callbacks) and ES7 async/await (to avoid callbacks at all and write asynchronous code that looks just like synchronous code).

Comment: Hi, I hope I am understanding this correctly, are you saying if client A perform synchronous above and the whole process takes 10 seconds and client B make the same query, client B has to wait for client A to finish?

Comment: `ES7 async/await` - not yet supported in node.js, so would need to be transpiled

Comment: @Zanko Assuming you're only running 1 instance of your web process, yes, that's correct. However, by using asynchronous code, client B can get a response while client A is still waiting on the DB to return the data.